# Can you expand an abelian group to have elements that satisfy a specific equation?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, model-theory

Given an abelian group $G$ and an equation of the form $$n_1 a_1 + ... + n_r a_r = m_1 y_1 + ... + m_k y_k$$where the $n_i$ and $m_i$ are positive integers and the $a_i$ are elements of $G$, is there guaranteed to be an abelian group containing $G$ as a subgroup such that there are $y_i$ satisfying the equation?

Comment: Note that since the left hand side is always in $G$ and we can always set $y_i=0$ for $i>1$, we can get a positive answer by showing: if $G$ is an abelian group, $g\in G$, and $m$ is a positive integer, then there is an abelian group $H\supseteq G$ with an element $h\in H$ satisfying $g=mh$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. It suffices to show that, for any $m>0$ and $a\in G$, there exists a injection of $\mathbb{Z}$-modules $\alpha:G\to H$ such that $\alpha(a)=my$ for some $y\in H$. (Why?) Thus let $H$ be the quotient of $G\times\mathbb{Z}$ by the subgroup $L\leqslant G$ generated by $(a,-m)$. We claim that the natural map $\alpha:G\to H$ taking $x$ to $(x,0)+L$ is an injection. Indeed, suppose $(x,0)+L$ is zero. Then $(x,0)\in L$, so $(x,0)=k(a,-m)=(ka,-km)$ for some $k\in\mathbb{Z}$. But, since $m>0$, we have $km\neq 0$ for every $k\in\mathbb{Z}\setminus\{0\}$, so this forces $k=0$ and thus $(x,0)=(0,0)$ and thus $x=0$, as desired. So indeed we may consider $G$ as a subgroup of $H$. But note that $$\alpha(a)=(a,0)+L=(a,0)-(a,-m)+L=(0,m)+L=m\big((0,1)+L\big),$$ so taking $y=(0,1)+L$ gives the desired solution.

---

The idea here is that, for a ring $R$, an index set $I$, and an $R$-module $M$, you can often use a suitable quotient of $M\times R^{\oplus I}$ to add $I$-many new elements to $M$ with properties you desired. (Some properties are not realizable in this way – for instance, we of course could not have taken $m=0$ in the above equation if $a\neq 0$ – but it's a useful slogan.) As an aside, since you tagged with `model-theory`, you may want to look into [pure-injective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraically_compact_module) modules, which deal precisely with solutions sets of the kind of equations you are considering. (The existence of simultaneous solutions to these kinds of equation is first-order expressable in the language $$\mathcal{L}_{R\text{-mod}}=(+,-,0,r)_{r\in R}$$ of $R$-modules, where each $r\in R$ is considered as a unary function symbol. These formulas are called "positive-primitive" formulas, and every $\mathcal{L}_{R\text{-mod}}$-formula is in fact, modulo the complete theory of any $R$-module, equivalent to a Boolean combination of positive primitive formulas.) A classic paper on the subject is [Ziegler's](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82056494.pdf).

Comment: Awesome! Does this extend to arbitrary systems of equations? And yes, I'm currently reading up on the quantifier elimination in abelian groups, which lead me to this question.

Comment: Actually, the equations $a_1 = y_1$ and $a_2 = y_1$ for non-equal $a_1$ and $a_2$ is a counterexample, since it can't be extended so that they are equal. But I wonder what the conditions on the equations are for solutions to be possible... perhaps something similar to the solvability conditions of linear systems?

Comment: @user2461616 ah, right on!! :) yes the various quantifier elimination results for modules (or abelian groups in particular) are very nice, and I believe it was the result for abelian groups which kickstarted a lot of the model theory of modules more generally? although I am not entirely sure of the history. anyway, re: your question, yes you have correctly identified the sticking point once you move to systems of multiple equations. unfortunately I am not sure if there are any "nice" conditions on when these systems are solvable in some extension... maybe worth asking as a separate question!!

Comment: I've asked it as a seperate question; meanwhile, could you recommend me some literature surrounding these questions? Perhaps something elaborating on the method of constructing quotients of extensions by $\mathbb{Z}$ with certain properties, which you mentioned?

Comment: @user2461616 nice, +1 on your question!! :) I will be very interested to see what answers you receive. re: quotients of this kind, I think much of my intuition for it comes from group *presentations* in the non-abelian context, which somehow make precise the idea of introducing a new element satisfying certain relations. there's a lot written about group presentations, but I am not sure if those are what you are looking for, as they are not specifically about abelian groups (and the behavior of free abelian groups is very different than free groups in general)