# When can an abelian group be expanded to satisfy some equations and not others?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, logic, modules, systems-of-equations

Given an abelian group $G$ and a system of equations A,
$$a_1 = n^1_1 x_1 + \cdots + n^1_r x_r$$
$$\vdots$$
$$a_s = n^s_1 x_1 + \cdots + n^s_r x_r$$
with $a_i \in G$ and $n^i_j \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$, we know (thanks to [Eric Wofsey](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4155094/931298)) that the existence of an extension of $G$ containing solutions to these equations is equivalent to the validity of a finite set of equations in the $a_i$; furthermore, there is a universal such extension, the pushout $G \oplus \mathbb{Z}^r / M$ where $M = \langle (- a_i, n^i_1, \ldots, n^i_r ) \mid 1 \leq i \leq s \rangle$.

My question is, given another system of equations B,
$$b_1 = m^1_1 y_1 + \cdots + n^1_t y_t$$
$$\vdots$$
$$b_v = m^v_1 y_1 + \cdots + n^v_t y_t$$
is there a similarly "nice" (first order) condition for the existence of an extension of $G$ containing a solution to A, but NO solutions to B?
Equivalently, is there a first-order condition for the universal extension of $G$ with solutions of A to not contain the universal extension with solutions of B?

Comment: For sure there is no universal extension, simply because "having no solution" is not preserved by homomorphisms.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg You mean there is no universal extension in which there is a solution to one system and not the other?

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg
I would think the natural one would be the universal extension $H$ admitting a solution to system A, if it exists, since if there were any such systems not admitting a solution to B then $H$ would not admit one